# Is it possible to add a group with the same group name in different OU?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have tried to add a group with the same group name (cn) in different OU in Active Directory.
It means that the DN of 2 groups should be different, but I was not able to do it in Active Directory.
Question if it is expected.
In addition, question if it is common LDAP behavior or Active Directory implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  It is not possible to have a group by the same name existing more than once within the same Active Directory.  It doesn't matter if it would be in two different OUs, giving it a different DN; the group name itself has to be unique.  The premise of the second question is interesting.  LDAP is an application protocol for querying and modifying items in a directory; Active Directory incorporates that *and* also includes a full-on directory services database, so when you speak of LDAP *behavior* this limitation in and of itself is not actually a limitation of LDAP.